# How does Laplace transform ℒ{ sin(t)/t } solves definite integral 0 to ∞ ∫ (sin(t)/t) dt

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform

How does the answer of the Laplace transform $$\mathcal L \left\{ \frac{\sin t}{t} \right\}= \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}(s)$$ solve the definite integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt = \frac{\pi}{2} $$

How are they related? why does this solve the definite integral?

Thank you.

Comment: Use Laplace of sint , then use.. division of t rule, which lets you integrate it from s to infty

Comment: I know how to do. I just don't know why it works??

Comment: Go through the derivation of division of t rule. You will understand why it works

Comment: I understand the division of t rule and how it works. What i do not understand is by taking the  Laplace transform ℒ{ sin(t)/t } it basically solve the definite integral?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \frac{\sin{t}}{t} e^{-s t} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan{s} $$

Plug in $s=0$ to both sides.

There are lots of ways to prove the LT.  One way to do it is to use the FT relation for the sinc term.

Comment: $s=0$ is a boundary point, hence you need an argument when taking the limit.

Comment: @AD. "hence?"  If the integral converges (and the OP is not questioning that), then I do not need to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Abel's theorem to take the limit as s goes to zero. Tis is needed because 0 is the boudary of the LT.